# update node with property list while keeping current properties (not with SET n.prop = 'x')

Tags: cypher

The Cypher `SET n={properties}` replaces all properties of a node, is there a way to only update the ones defined in properties collection and not destroy the current ones not defined in properties?

This to me would be a mess since I would have to define all the values and update cypher queries all the time after my validation already filtered out what is allowed:

```
SET n.fname = {properties}.fname, n.lname = {properties}.lname, n.age = 18, ...
```

As I know this will keep the previous properties which I don't define in `SET`.

I'd rather use something like `SET` with my collection and leave the properties not defined as they are.

```
SET n = {properties}  // but not destroy properties not defined in properties collection
```

if there isn't a way, is there maybe a means of getting them all, then merging them based on the passed collection al in the same query? Otherwise I'll have to first do a get, then merge them, and then do a set.

Using Neo4j 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SET n += {props}`](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-set.html#set-adding-properties-from-maps). I guess it's available since 2.1.0.

Comment: Interesting answer, I tried match (t:Test {name: 'TEST'}) set t += {test: 'test123', description: 'nothin'} and worked, where did you find this in the docs I'm wondering??? Thanks!

Comment: I found it in the [refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.2/cypher-refcard/), it's a great cheatsheet.

Answer (score 2):

They introduced MERGE in version 2.0.1. That should solve your problem. 
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html

Answer (score 0):

At this point it isn't possible in one shot with cypher.  Support for maps is pretty new (read: limited), so expect to see improvements in the future.  Here are some related Github issues, if you're curious to follow the progress:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/33

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1695

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1696